# Работа с циклом do/while

Tags: javascript

Написать программу, которая на вопрос "остановить программу?", запрашивает ответ "да", программа должна остановиться только если пользователь введет "да".
/*Заранее спасибо

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автор даже не пытался что-то сделать.

Answer (score 1):

С циклом do/while такой фокус не пройдет. Он же выполняется синхронно и процесс просто зависнет на бесконечном цикле.

Другой вариант сделать что-то похожее - воспользоваться интервалом. Например так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/f5xmrb7d/

```
var $stop = $("#stop"),
    $debug = $("#debug"),
    flag = true,
    i = 0;

$stop.on("click", function () {
    var conf = window.confirm("Stop the program?");
    if (conf) {
        flag = false;
    }
});

var inter = setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    $debug.html(i);

    if (!flag) {
        clearInterval(inter);
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Где Ваш код?
Сделать это легко:

```js
var answer = null, i = 0;
do{
  console.info("Итерация №" + i);
  i++;
  answer = prompt("Остановить программу?");
  if(answer == null) // Fix to "No" button
    answer = "";
}while(answer.toLowerCase() !== 'да');
```